# Digital Signature or MAC Yielding Non-Binary Verification Predicate

Tags: signature, mac

Is there a digital signature or MAC scheme in which, the verification algorithm returns not $\{\text{Valid},\text{Invalid}\}$, but a discrete (finite or infinite) set of result such as $\{\text{Valid-for-A}, \text{Valid-for-B}, \text{Valid-for-C}, \text{Invalid-for-All}\}$?

This is a curiosity question. There is no limit on the nature of the scheme, it can be symmetric or asymmetric, classical, or post-quantum.

**EDIT**

To explain why could potentially be "Valid-for-{A,B,C}":

1. In PKC there could be 3 (or any number of) private keys derived from a master private key (possibly using some form of key-escrow), that can be identified and verified by the "master" public key. An application of such scheme could be "bandwidth-efficient group member authentication".
2. In symmetric-key cryptography, it could be an multi-party broadcast domain authenticated encryption, in which ciphertext verification don't require computing the tag with each of the peers' key - the recipiant instead somehow use the shared key to "decrypt" or "derive" the peer's key. Same application as above.

Comment: What are A,B,C? Parties? Or purposes? As in "this signature is valid as authentication in an AKE, but not as an email signature"?

Comment: What exactly is prohibiting you from just looping over all possible public keys / entities to achieve the same result? Are you expecting a huge number of entities rather than 3? If that's feasible I think you're overdoing it. Otherwise I'm thinking about ECDSA where you can retrieve the public key from the signature, allowing you to only compare against a hash value of that public key (although a compressed public key and hash value are not that different in size, so that's for specific use cases only).